# Getting the 114 error with Parse.com registering an Android Device for Push Notifications

Tags: parse-platform

I'm gettin an error with parse.com when I try to register an Android token device, for push notifications.

This is my request:

> {
>
> "deviceType": "android",
>
> "deviceToken": "MY DEVICE ANDROID TOKEN",
>
> "installationId": "acef4da2-98e8-484f-9688-cbb1c6a27c8e",
>
> "channels": [
>       ""   ]
>
> }

and I get this response:

> {
>
> "code": 114,
>
> "error": "deviceToken may not be set for deviceType android"
>
> }

Someone knows why I get this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the error too and solved it.

Registering an android device, You should add pushType.

Refer to : http://upbeat-sound.tistory.com/24

Answer (score 0):

From the push notification guide in the parse docs:

"deviceToken: The Apple generated token used for iOS devices, or the token used by GCM to keep track of registration ID (readonly)."

the field is readonly, and you are trying to write to it.

Comment: You are wrong. He uses REST API, which allows you to register / modify all fields of Installations objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().save();
```

This will automatically save your device info in as an Installation Object.

Comment: the problem is, that sometimes you cannot. If you have your own / third party plugin for GCM, then Parse plugin will not receive deviceToken (GCM registration id) and it will always be null. So the only way to set deviceToken is through REST API.